# Installed libphp-mailer on ubuntu server, how can I use it in web projects?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server, phpmailer

I have been trying to use the mail() function without any success : I don't have any precise errors, and it returns "true" but the email is never received.

sendmail works from command line by doing `echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v nono88@emailaddy.com` in the ssh shell, the email is sent.

Therefore I am trying to install and use PHPmailer see if that could help. It could probably give more information about any failures. So, I have ran apt-get install libphp-phpmailer and it installed the needed files into `/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer`.

How can I simply include the php files needed in the script I want to try, knowing that all my projects are `in /var/www/html/[...]` ?

Comment: you could build a wrapper with `shell_exec()`

Comment: @Insax Thanks for the suggestion. As I'm a total noob when it comes to server stuff, can you tell me it is really hard to do ? I will try to get a tutorial see if I could manage to follow directions and do that. Also will try to understand what a wrapper does as I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: A wrapper is an interface for your LibPHP mailer. In order to send emails you have to use `shell_exec()`, but shell_exec is security risk because you can call a lot of commands on your shell. Therfore you have to make sure that there are NO other commands sent through injection, you can also have a look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: What? Of course you don't need to use `shell_exec`! PHPMailer deals with that for you, and that's what is in the libphp-phpmailer package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd warn against using this PHPMailer package as it is based on an old version from 2015. While it has Debian-supplied patches for some serious security vulnerabilities, it does not have all the bug fixes or feature additions from the last 2 years, of which there are many. I suggest using [composer](https://getcomposer.org) to manage your PHP packages as it's generally easier and much more up to date.

Anyway, after installation from this Debian package, you'll find it in `/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer`, so if you take one of the examples provided with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable), replace the line that loads PHPMailer's autoloader with this:

```
require '/usr/share/php/libphp-phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

Note that this approach is obsolete and will not work with [the current release of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) (6.0.x), so you might want to get on with switching to the new version now, while you're writing fresh code.

Comment: Excellent information given and I really appreciate the good advice, I will try to un-install the libphp-phpmailer package then. I will use composer for the first time and follow instructions, it can't be that difficult. Thank you very much Synchro , very clear answer.

Comment: @Syncho : I installed PHPMail with composer. It added a vendor folder. However when I try to make a test , I get 'Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer'' . So i've also downloaded the PHPMailer-master.zip file from github. I've looked for 2 files: class.phpmailer.php and PHPMailerAutoload.php because I think that they are missing . But None of them are inside the -master folder, and I don't have them in the "vendor" folder either. I am confused.

Comment: Make sure you're basing your code on a recent example - you're probably missing `use` statements to import the PHPMailer classes into your namespace. Also, you need to load `vendor/autoload.php` instead of the old PHPMailer autoloader.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the file "class.phpmailer.php" isn't needed anymore ? So I have the files: PHPMailer.php inside the src folder, and I ve tryed with : use \vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer; as well as use  \var\www\html\testsite.com\aef456\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer; but I'm still getting "Class 'PHPMailer' not found". So I moved the file PHPMailer.php from the src directory to the same level as the script i'm trying, and therefore have replaced by " use PHPMailer; ". But I get the same error. The script i'm trying is on https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

Comment: Well I got a more precise error:  "The use statement with non-compound name 'PHPMailer' has no effect" . Not really sure how I can fix that.

Comment: At last, it seem to be working. I thought that "use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" was a path!  to the file PHPMailer.php . I 've neved used 'use' ( no pun intended). Hugh what a relief!... Thanks for the help. edit - even got the email, great. This PHPMailer looks promising!

Comment: Glad you worked that out - welcome to namespaces in PHP!

Comment: For simplicity, you can shorten that to require 'libphp-phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  Check our include path but /usr/share/php should be in your include path already.  Updated 2021 version...  require 'libphp-phpmailer/autoload.php';